# How to efficiently change column type in table without dropping db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table called 'deliveries' which I already migrated via rake db:migrate as seen below:

I made a mistake naming my tables and want to learn the most efficient way to change the column delivertime, which is currently defined as an t.integer in the table, into t.datetime instead.

```
class CreateDeliveries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :deliveries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :deliveryaddress
      t.integer :deliverytime
      t.string :notes
      t.references :orders, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my schema for more context:

```
 create_table "deliveries", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.string   "deliveryaddress"
   t.integer  "deliverytime"
   t.string   "notes"
   t.integer  "order_id"
   t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

  add_index "deliveries", ["order_id"], name: "index_deliveries_on_order_id"

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "pickup"
    t.datetime "pickuptime"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end
```

What is the most efficient way to do this without having to drop the table (tried this before and it just caused lots of db migration errors)? Thank you.

**Next, I went into the command line and entered rails g migration ChangeColumnDeliveryTime.  No new file was generated in my db/migrate folder, which is what I found confusing.  So I had to go into the command line and find its appropriate name, 20160211115009_rename_order_ids_column.rb

Next I included the following:

```
 class ChangeColumnDeliveryTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    change_column(:deliveries, :deliverytime, :datetime)
  end
end
```

Then, I ran rake db:migrate.  I did not see the updated changes to my column in my local environment, even after restarting the rails server.

What is causing this latest issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't work for you, because you can not migrate integer to datetime, as DB server won't know how to cast it.

I can suggest you this 2 ways of doing it:

- Rename current column from deliverytime to deliverytime_temp
- Create new column called deliverytime with datetime type
- Update all rows with casted value with casted value
- Remove deliverytime_temp column

Here's code snippet:

```
class ChangeColumnDeliveryTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column(:deliveries, :deliverytime, :deliverytime_temp)
    add_column(:deliveries, :deliverytime, :datetime)  
  end
end
```

And data migration:

```
class MigrateDeliveryTimeDates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def up
    Delivery.reset_column_information

    Delivery.find_each do |delivery|
      delivery.update_column(:deliverytime,  Time.at(delivery.deliverytime_temp))
    end
  end        
end
```

Or you can try other way and find a way to alter column with cast (`to_timestamp` + `ALTER [ COLUMN ] column [ SET DATA ] TYPE type [ USING expression ]` 
may be useful.

But if it's rather new database - go with first solution

Comment: After following the suggestion exactly above, I get a pending migration error after I run rake db:migrate.  When I added the new migration via rails g MigrateDeliveryTimeDates, no new file was generated under db/migrate so I created it manually (not sure if this is unusual).  The error reads: "An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: undefined method `deliverytime_temp' ."  Why is that?

Comment: When you run `rake db:migrate`, it loads the app on the beginning and fetches the schema for each model. If you rename column in the migration, the Delivery model is not notified about this change, thus it does not set it.

I've updated the code with `reset_column_information` added

Comment: Also - remember that I did not handle the reverse migration and did not get rid of temp column, what you probably would like to do is to add next migration that does the same as first one but in other direction, define `down` method on the data migration (2nd) one and remove temp column in each of them

Answer (score 3):

Changes the column to a different type using the same parameters as add_column.

```
change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: Thanks, Charles!  I actually deployed the changes your recommended above but for some reason the column is unchanged.  I've included a more detail explanation above with code.  In short, when I ran rails g migration ChangeColumnDeliveryTime in the cmd line to follow your suggestion, the first peculiar thing I noticed is that  it didn't generate a new file in db/migrate. What could have gone wrong here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try change_column
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column

or remove_column followed by add_column in the same migration.

You shouldn't need to drop the table, but I don't see how doing that would affect your migrations. You could post your full schema if you are still having problems.